# Javascript addEventListener doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form used to reset a password. On client side I am using vannila js to check if the input is valid however the javascript code doesn't execute completely. It gets the form,password and repeated password id's but it doesn't stop the form from submitting or executing the validation functions.

This is the password reset form. For server side I am using php to check if the proper values exist. If they don't the user can't access the page and the form doesn't exist. However all the data exists so I can see the form

```
<?php
require_once "../classes/dbh.classes.php";
require_once "../classes/reset-password.class.php";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!--Bootstrap link -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Bootstrap icons link-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <!--Mapbox css link (optional)-->
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet'/>

    <!--Custom styles link-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css">

    <!--JQUERY LINK-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>LP Budgeting - reset password</title>
</head>
<body>


<!--HEADER START-->
<!--navbar start-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-black navbar-dark py-3 fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="../index.php" class="navbar-brand">LP<span class="text-warning">Budgeting</span></a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler"
                type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navmenu"
        >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="../index.php" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!--navbar end-->
<!--HEADER END-->


<!--RESET PASSWORD FORM START-->
<div class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5>Reset your password</h5>
                        <p>Please fill out the fields below and your password will be changed</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <?php
                        if ($_GET['token'] && $_GET['email']) {
                            $token = $_GET['token'];
                            $email = $_GET['email'];

                            $check_user_class = new reset_password();
                            if ($check_user_class->check_user_4reset($email, $token)) {
                                ?>
                                <form method="post" name="reset-form" id="reset-form" action="submit_new_password.php">
                                    <?php
                                    $fullUrl = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

                                    if (strpos($fullUrl, "error=passwords-mismatch") == true) {
                                        if (isset($_SESSION["password-mismatch"])) {
                                            echo $_SESSION["password-mismatch"];
                                            unset($_SESSION["password-mismatch"]);
                                        }
                                    } elseif (strpos($fullUrl, "error=empty_fields") == true) {
                                        if (isset($_SESSION['empty-passwords'])) {
                                            echo $_SESSION["empty-passwords"];
                                            unset($_SESSION["empty-passwords"]);
                                        }

                                    } else {
                                        if (isset($_SESSION["password-change-success"])) {
                                            echo $_SESSION["password-change-success"];
                                            unset($_SESSION["password-change-success"]);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
                                        <label for="password">Enter New password</label>
                                        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name='password'
                                               placeholder="New password"><br>
                                        <label for="password2">Repeat your password</label>
                                        <input type="password" id="password2" class="form-control"
                                               name='password_repeat' placeholder="Repeat your password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                        <input type="submit" id="submit_password" name="submit_password"
                                               class="btn btn-primary">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <!--Custom Javascript-->
                                <script src="../js/password-reset-error-handling.js" type="module"></script>
                                <!--RESET PASSWORD FORM END-->
                                <?php
                            } else {
                                //That user doesn't exist
                                echo "error";
                            }


                        }
                        ?>


<!--Javascript/Bootstrap links-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

The javascript code

```
const reset_form = document.getElementById('reset-form');
const password = document.getElementById('password');
const password_repeat = document.getElementById('password2');/////////////////all of these variables have the proper value i.e the id of the input fields and the form


reset_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {    /////////this is the part that it skips 


    if (validateInputs()) {
        e.currentTarget.submit();
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});


function validateInputs() {
    //Get the value from inputs
    const passwordValue = password.value.trim();
    const passwordRepeatValue = password_repeat.value.trim();
    let return_value = false;

    //These variables are set with one when the value of the input field is correct
    let password_check = 0;
    let password_repeat_check = 0;


    if (passwordValue === '') {
        //Show error and set error class
        setError(password, 'Password field cannot be empty');
    } else if (passwordValue.length <= 6) {
        setError(password, 'Please enter a longer password');

    } else {
        //Add success class
        setSuccess(password);
        password_check = 1;
    }

    if (passwordRepeatValue === '') {
        //Show error and set error class
        setError(password_repeat, 'Password repeat field cannot be empty');
    } else if (passwordValue !== passwordRepeatValue) {
        setError(password_repeat, 'The passwords do not match');
    } else if (passwordRepeatValue.length <= 6) {
        setError(password_repeat, "Repeated password needs to be longer")
    } else {
        //Add success class
        setSuccess(password_repeat);
        password_repeat_check = 1;
    }

    if (name_check === 1 && email_check === 1 && password_check === 1 && password_repeat_check === 1) {
        return_value = true;
    } else {
        return_value = false;
    }

    return return_value;


}


function setError(element, message) {
    element.className = "form-control error";
    const small = document.getElementById("message-" + element.id);
    small.classList.remove('success');

    //Add error message and icon
    small.innerHTML = message + ' <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle">';
    //Add error class
    small.classList.add("error");


}

const setSuccess = (element) => {
    element.className = "form-control success";
    const small = document.getElementById("message-" + element.id);
    small.classList.remove('error');

    //Add success icon
    small.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check-circle">';
    //Add success class
    small.classList.add("success");

}
```

Comment: are there any errors visible in the browser console?

Comment: @RobinZigmond no errors the code is loaded just skipped

Comment: Your JS seems fine. I suspect you might be dealing with a race condition or other conditional issues due to the PHP conditions in your HTML. Have you tried putting `<script src="../js/password-reset-error-handling.js" type="module"></script>` just before your `</body>` tag?

Comment: @tgikf yes I did try that. Nothing changed. I put the <script> tag before </html> and now it works ok. Still thanks for the help